# To count how many time a particular song listened in playlist

Tags: java, android-studio, counting, android-music-player

Please help- I am stuck at this part I want to know how to count a particular song in playlist whenever it pressed(say xyz song).By java programming.
Pls help me... I am very grateful to you if you give some time to me to overcome this problem

Comment: Hi Vishal. Your question is rather vague.  I suggest you review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to clarify what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Sir I want to know(eg. If i play song(say xyz song) 5 times in media player then how can I count the song by Java program that how many time I listened it

Comment: Do you have a Most Played playlist or something? If so, show us the codes.